# Jquery ajax usar variable en path

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

necesito crear el url con una variable. En el código obtengo lo que deseo generar en el path con la variable "cPath", luego al utilizarla en "{{ path() }} me da error. Ya probe de varias formas ¿Alguna sugerencia? Al poner dentro del path una expresion de forma directa no hay problema, pero necesito que sea mediante una variable. Gracias

```
jQuery(".updater").on("click", function(){
    var trg  = jQuery(this).attr("trg");
    var cPath  = jQuery(this).attr("mtd"); /* variable a utilizar */
    var oCmb = jQuery("#" + trg);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('"+cPath+"') }}", /* aca genera el error */
```

Comment: ¿`cPath` es una ruta relativa o absoluta?

Comment: El contenido de la variable es : "ctCto-getPrv" y debe llevar a este metodo /**
     * @Route("/contactos/getPrv",  name="ctCto-getPrv")
     */
    public function getPrv()
    {

Comment: @jluishg parece que estuvieras usando angular con esas rutas que mencionas, pero seguro me estoy equivocando supongo que eso es de `symfony`, en vez de hacer eso deberias buscar un metodo en `symfony` o su documentacion que permita hacer eso sin necesidad de colocar ese codigo, ya que tecnicamente si es parecido a angular habran formas mucho mejores, menos peligrosas y rapidas de hacer lo que deseas, solo es mirar bien la documentacion, estoy seguro que debe haber algo mejor en la documentacion de symfony.

Comment: por ejemplo en angular existe `NavController` que permite ir hacia una ruta solo colocando el nombre del componente al que deseas ir.